# Direct connection to mongo hidden instance in a replica set

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a Mongo hidden member as part of a replica set that is dedicated to tasks such as reporting and insights (long time running tasks). We connect to the instance directly using mongoose 5.7.4 as follow:

```js
mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://mongo-hidden-instance:27017/dbname',
   {
        useNewUrlParser: false,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        readPreference: "secondaryPreferred",
        socketTimeoutMS: 1800000
    }, cb);
```

We can connect correctly to the instance and run our queries. But if the hidden instance is down our connection, that has been kept alive, is reaching another member of the replica set. This behavior is something we didn't expect and we don't want, we want to run long time queries only on the hidden instance.

How can I connect only to the hidden instance and if it's down to get an error instead of connecting to another member of the replica set?

Comment: Di you try `secondary` instead of `secondaryPreferred`?

Comment: Even with ``secondary`` is connecting to other replica set member.

Answer (score 0):

as MongoDB sayed https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-preference/

> secondaryPreferred : In most situations, operations read from secondary members but if no secondary members are available, operations read from the primary on sharded clusters.

> secondary: All operations read from the secondary members of the replica set.

so you need to change

```
        readPreference: "secondaryPreferred",
```

to

```
        readPreference: "secondary",
```

Comment: I tried but is still connecting to a secondary instance even if the only one with the option ``secondaryOk = true`` is the hidden one. I need to connect only to the hidden instance and get an error if the hidden instance is down. I don't want to run long time queries on a secondary that is not the hidden one.